# Java Selenium ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set up to use `Selenium 4.18.1` using `Java 11`, but I am facing `ClassNotFoundException`.

I put all the jar files (including the lib folder) for the `Java` binding folder as a project build path on [Selenium Download Page](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) on that site.

[List of jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbcPP.png)

[List of jars 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ksqz.png)

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", D:\\googleDrive\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
driver.quit();
```

Also, Google Chrome Drive also has files that fit the latest version.

`ClassNotFoundException` occurs when server boots after project clean. There is no error in that Java file, but I don't know why.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
```

If anyone knows anything about it, I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: While not a direct answer: You can use Gradle or Maven to take care of dependency management and thus also downloading and packaging libraries.